# How to reference multiple columns in case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query, where i'm attempting to use a case statement referencing two columns.

Data:

Users table:

```
ID_User       sUserName
1             Test
2             Test2
3             Test3
```

Customers table:

```
ID        last name       Redeemed        paid
1           Cust1         10/1/16         9/15/16
2           Cust2         9/16/16         9/14/16
3           Cust3         10/4/16         9/30/16
4           Cust4         10/5/16         10/1/16
```

Query:

```
SELECT     Users.sUserName, Customers.LastName, CASE WHEN customers.Redeemed < '9/28/16' AND 
                      customers.paid < '9/28/16' THEN '3' ELSE '4' END AS Amount
FROM         Customers LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      Users ON Customers.lGreeterId = Users.ID_User
WHERE     (Customers.Redeemed BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate)
```

Output of the query:

```
susername  last name      amount

Test        Cust1           4
Test2       Cust2           4
Test3       Cust3           4
Test3       Cust4           4
```

Output should be:

```
susername  last name      amount

 Test        Cust1           3
 Test2       Cust2           3
 Test3       Cust3           4
 Test3       Cust4           4
```

Why am I getting the "else" result for all of them?  I am looking to return a '3' if redeemed is less than the specified date `OR` paid is less than the specified date.

Paid and Redeemed are both Datatype `datetime`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following comments, try using a different date format in the query

```
SELECT     Users.sUserName, Customers.LastName, 
           CASE 
             WHEN customers.Redeemed < '2016-09-28' THEN '3'
             WHEN customers.paid < '2016-09-28' THEN '3' 
             ELSE '4'
           END AS Amount
FROM         Customers 
LEFT JOIN Users 
    ON Customers.lGreeterId = Users.ID_User
WHERE     (Customers.Redeemed BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate)
```

Comment: I am looking for an AND, not an OR -

Comment: @Shmewnix then it's your datatypes that are banjaxed

Comment: My datatypes are both 'datetime'

Comment: Same result.  Although - I'm looping through the results here of your initial query, and for some reason, it doesn't appear to be returning "Or" results, instead it appears to be delivering "AND" results - I don't quite understand that.

Comment: @Shmewnix You have the concepts of AND and OR backwards, mate. So, if it meets BOTH criteria it is an AND. If it meets either, it is an OR. For Cust1 to return, you need an OR.

Comment: duh!  Thanks! If you change your Answer back - I'll accept it.  Thanks for the sanity check.